# How to remove the total row from cart and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I would like to remove only  total row on cart and checkout page not the whole block. 
I am not able to find any action or filter to remove the  total i still want to leave the subtotal . 
I am using the code below but it hides the whole order block and also it does not remove it from the bill that is generated after checkout

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'remove_checkout_totals', 1 );

      function remove_checkout_totals()
   {remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );}
```

Comment: You need to override the related templates like [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277895/remove-subtotal-line-from-cart-and-checkout-pages-in-woocommerce/53292251#53292251)… There are no hooks for that on cart and checkout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not find any hook specified for the Total row because they are hard coded in the templates the only way to remove the total row from the cart page and checkout pages by modifying those pages template and to do that you need to follow few steps as follow:

1. Create Folder in your child theme called `woocommerce`.
2. Create two folders inside main `woocommerce` which you just created called name `checkout` and `cart`.
3. now create file called `review-order.php` put it inside `checkout` folder and `cart-totals.php` put it inside the `cart` folder then copy the content from the original files which you can find in `wp-content/plugins/woocoomerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php`  and `wp-content/plugins/woocoomerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php`

**Last step:**

find the following lines in both files and delete them:

```
    <tr class="order-total">
       <th><?php _e('Total', 'woocommerce'); ?></th>
       <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

**Order received page**

To Remove the Total from Order received page you can use `woocommerce_get_order_item_totals` hook and unset the total as follow:

```
add_action('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'remove_total', 10, 1);

function remove_total($array)
{
    unset($array['order_total']);
    return $array;
}
```

put the code above in your `functions.php`

That's it.

Comment: this is great , it worked , but it still did not solve the second part of the problem , the total is still being showed to the order receipt after placing order.

Comment: @king10 i have updated my answer and included the order received page

Comment: yes that one , it still show the total , it seems that the steps above only hide the field , it does not remove it for further process

Comment: @king10 let me know if the updated answer solved your problem

Comment: @kasalo yes it did , thanks a million , its perfect !!

Answer (score 0):

There is `order-total` class for order total. You should add a line of code into your css. It should solve the problem.

```css
.order-total { display: none; }
```